# Trying to convert tuple with ndarrays inside to another ndarray with additional dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have tuple a, which elements are np.ndarrays and I want to convert a to np.ndarray too. Like this:

```
a = np.ndarray(a)
```

But getting such error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. Tried also to convert inner arrays to the list, but got incorrect results. If my inner arrays have 3 dimensions, after all I want to have a ndarray with 4 dimensions. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: If so, there goes such error: "'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".
I also tried to convert from tuple to list and then to ndarrays, but problem was still

Comment: Read the docs.  Compare `np.array` with `np.ndarray`.  They don't take the same inputs.  `np.stack` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `numpy.ndarray` is not for creating with data.

[The docs say:](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

> Arrays should be constructed using array, zeros or empty (refer to the See Also section below). The parameters given here refer to a low-level method (ndarray(…)) for instantiating an array.

Try using `numpy.array`.

Your error would be that the tuple is for the first argument `shape` which is a tuple of integers.

You could create one from scratch with `np.ndarray` and the correct tuple instead perhaps.